# Stochastic Universal Sampling: Selecting Pairs for Crossover and Mutation

Tags: c#, genetic-algorithm

I'm a little confused on selecting chromosome **pairs** with **Stochastic Universal Sampling**. I understand how you can select offspring from a given population using this method. What I'm confused about, is how you select pairs from these offspring to be used for crossover/mutation.

**For example:**

- With plain *Roulette Wheel Selection*, you can roll the proverbial dice
  twice to grab 2 chromosomes for crossover/mutation, add them to the
  new population, and then continue until the new population is filled.
- With *Rank Selection*, you can order the current population by fitness
  ascending, assign a rank, and use rank/totalRank as the probability
  for roulette wheel selection, using the method above.
- How does this work with *Stochastic Universal Sampling*? You can
  select N chromosomes for crossover/mutation. You could then select
  pairs from the selected chromosomes to be used for crossover, but
  how? Randomly? Roulette Wheel Selection? If you use Roulette Wheel
  Selection, doesn't this bring back the same problem with Roulette
  Wheel Selection having too large a of a bias towards large fitness
  gaps?

Have I missed a step?

Comment: I would try asking this on http://cs.stackexchange.com or http://scicomp.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than just select two parents at a time, select the whole lot in one go.  Spin the imaginary roulette wheel to get a starting point then step around the wheel in fixed size steps, as many times as required, to select subsequent parents.

Once you have all the required parents you should shuffle them before using them to avoid bias towards pairs that are adjacent on the wheel.

Comment: I agree with Dan: Randomly shuffling all N sampled parents avoids any bias and you can then take two and two subsequent parents for crossover. You can e.g. use [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) for performing the shuffle.

Comment: Ahh, that seems like a valid approach.